# Regular expression to not allow 2/3/4 consecutive zeros in string

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, regex

I want to validate my textfield: Do not want to allow below entries in my textbox:

100123456- 2 repeating zeros with max length 9

120005689- 3 repeating zeros max length 9

100005689- 4 repeating zeros max length 9

I have tried below regex:

```
/^(?!.*(.)\1)(^[1-9][0-9]{8}$)/
```

It works, but it also do not allow repeating for other numbers.
eg: 114564568- because 1 is repeating

I only want it for Zeros. If there are consecutive zeros show an error.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex that will disallow 2 consecutive `0`s:

```
^(?!.*00)([1-9][0-9]{8})$
```

Or another version:

```
^(?!.*0{2})([1-9][0-9]{8})$
```

Any 9-digit number starting with a digit other than `0`, and that does not have `00` will pass. Actually, if we do not allow 2 consecutive zeros, we won't allow 3 and 4 consecutive zeros at the same time.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iN3jN0/8).

Comment: You are welcome. Your initial regex is more complicated than the one you needed, so I just downgraded it :) Also, it is not necessary to repeat the `^` anchor after a look-ahead, as we are still in the beginning of a string at that time.